# Toggle ListView Content on Button Click

Tags: android, list, button, switch-statement, toggle

[image]

In Main Activity I am displaying a List View populated from an sqlite DB. I wish to toggle between sorting the list alphabetically or numerically when the swap view icon is pressed.

I have tried doing something like this, but then I found that strings can only be assigned once and after that are unchangeable.

Here's the gist of what I have below. Is there a more standard way of implementing this functionality?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_swap_view:

            if (SWAP_VIEW_STATE == "sortbyname") {

                SWAP_VIEW_STATE = "sortbynumber";

            } else {
                SWAP_VIEW_STATE = "sortbyname"; 
    }
            // Pass in SWAP_VIEW_STATE and use if condition on database.rawQuery()

     PopulateListView(SWAP_VIEW_STATE) 

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change SWAP_VIEW_STATE == "sortbyname" 
to SWAP_VIEW_STATE.equals("sortbyname") and try

Comment: .equals() only checks to see if the string = something else. It doesn't actually assign a new value to the string.
                                                                                                            
public boolean equals(Object anObject)
Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Returns:
true if the given object represents a String equivalent to this string, false otherwise